# Propositional Logic Modus Ponens

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, system, agent

I'm trying to design an robot with propositional logic and I am trying to prove that there is a resource at 4,2 using modus ponens and resolution rule but I am stuck if you can help

- robots in (2, 2) detect a cliff around,
- there is no cliff in (2, 1) and in (1, 2),
- robots in (2, 4) do not detect any cliff around,
- there is no resource r1 in (3, 1) and in (2, 2),
- either there is no resource r1 in (3, 3) or there is a cliff in (3, 4)
- also if there is a cliff there is a resource in an adjacent location and if there is at most one cliff next adjacent to a resource